# Adding an equal number to the numerator and denominatior of a positive rational number

Tags: calculus, number-theory

If $\frac pq \in Q$, and $p,q \in I^+$ then:

a)`$\frac pq > 1$

Adding a constant, positive integer $\epsilon$ to both p and q will reduce the value of the fraction and bring it closer to 1.

Thus $\frac{p+\epsilon}{q+\epsilon} < \frac pq$

b) $\frac pq < 1$

Adding a constant, positive integer $\epsilon$ to both p and q will increase the value of the fraction and bring it closer to 1.

Thus $\frac{p+\epsilon}{q+\epsilon} > \frac pq$

Is this a valid result, and can one prove it using calculus?

Comment: b is not necessarily correct if $\frac{p}{q}<0$.

Comment: Thanks, let me edit that bit out.

Comment: You're welcome. I meant that you should observe this case more carefully, but I'm not entirely sure that my claim is correct.

Comment: It seems to hold true empirically; but I can be the biggest dunce when it comes to Mathematics :)
Although that never really stops me from trying to understand someone's analysis of a topic/theory

Comment: Perhaps you want $p$ and $q$ to be positive integers, instead of the fraction being positive.  With that change, the statements don't need calculus to be proved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results that you claim are not true when $p$ and $q$ are not positive integers.  For example, let $p=-3$ and $q=-2$.  Then $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{3}{2}>1$.  Then, let $\epsilon=1$, then $\frac{p+\epsilon}{q+\epsilon}=\frac{-2}{-1}=2>\frac{3}{2}$.

So, we will assume that $p$ and $q$ are positive integers.

**Calculus solution:**

Consider the function $\frac{p+x}{q+x}$.  Its derivative is $$\frac{(q+x)-(p+x)}{(q+x)^2}=\frac{q-p}{(q+x)^2}.$$

If $\frac{p}{q}>1$, then $p>q$ and the derivative is negative for all $x$, so $\frac{p+x}{q+x}$ is a decreasing function.  Then, using the observation by @RobbeMotmans, you get that the function is decreasing to 1.

If $\frac{p}{q}<1$, then $p<q$ and the derivative is positive for all $x$, so $\frac{p+x}{q+x}$ is an increasing function.  Then, using the observation by @RobbeMotmans, you get that the function is increasing to 1.

**Elementary solution**

If $\frac{p}{q}>1$, then $p>q$.  We can multiply both sides of the inequality by $\epsilon$ without changing the direction of the inequality to get $p\epsilon>q\epsilon$.  Then, adding $pq$ to both sides, one gets $pq+p\epsilon>pq+q\epsilon$.  Factoring, we have 
$$p(q+\epsilon)>q(p+\epsilon).$$
Now, we can divide by $q(q+\epsilon)$ which is positive and does not change the direction of the inequality to get
$\frac{p}{q}>\frac{p+\epsilon}{q+\epsilon}.$

If $\frac{p}{q}<1$, then $p<q$.  We can multiply both sides of the inequality by $\epsilon$ without changing the direction of the inequality to get $p\epsilon<q\epsilon$.  Then, adding $pq$ to both sides, one gets $pq+p\epsilon<pq+q\epsilon$.  Factoring, we have 
$$p(q+\epsilon)<q(p+\epsilon).$$
Now, we can divide by $q(q+\epsilon)$ which is positive and does not change the direction of the inequality to get
$\frac{p}{q}<\frac{p+\epsilon}{q+\epsilon}.$

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to separate this problem.
if $\frac pq \in \Bbb{Q}$ then $p \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $q \in \Bbb{Z}$.

$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{p+x}{q+x} = 1$ for all $p,q \in \Bbb{Z}$

So you can say it is a valid result.